# Using polymer with groovy template in Play 1 framework

Tags: groovy, playframework-1.x, polymer-1.0

I've simplified the code to the core. There is a custom element < my-button >:

```
<link rel="import" href="/public/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="my-button">
    <template>
        <button onclick = "custom_click()">&{common.TWords.REGION_MAP}</button>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "my-button"
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

and index file where I'm using my-button:

```
 #{extends 'layouts/activ_page_template.html' /}
#{set title: play.i18n.Messages.get(common.TWords.ACTIVSITE_MENU_CONTACTS).concat(" | activ") /}
<script src="/public/javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/public/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>

    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    #{page_gradient_title}
        &{common.TWords.ACTIVSITE_TOPLINKS_CONTACTS}
    #{/page_gradient_title}
  </div>
</div>
//following two lines are in question
    #{polymer/my-button /}
    <my-button></my-button>
```

If I html import custom tags groovy template elements used in light DOM, such as 
&{common.TWords.REGION_MAP} is not going to be rendered, it will be just copied verbatim. But if I import the tag in groovy template way, like this #{polymer/my-button /}, it only works in Google Chrome. 
The problem is with other browsers, such as Mozilla firefox. In that browser I get an error "ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined", because html import happens in the very end naturally leaving Polymer objects in custom tags undefined. Is it possible to use groovy template inside custom element's local DOM, if it is then how?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot try this directly, but you can try these steps:

- MyButton must be a tag or better a parts of dynamic html template (es. in `app/views/parts/polymerLibrary.html`) `#include`d in your page
- every link in tag `<link rel="import" href="...">` must be refered with Play Framework Groovy syntax, i.e. `@{'/public/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'}`
- **most important**: every import referred as absolute URL with  `@@{'/public/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'}` (notice double `@`)

Try these and let us know if they work.